# Insert image from its path to mysql and retrieve it into <img> tag using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I tried to insert image from its path into mysql database using php and I did it but when I need to retrieve the image from mysql database into  tag the image doesn't appear.

my database

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_images` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `name` blob NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

index.php

```html
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  
 if(isset($_POST["insert"]))  
 {  
    $path='C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test_img\\4.jpg';
      $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images(name) VALUES ('LOAD_FILE($path)')";  
      if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
      {  
           echo '<script>alert("Image Inserted into Database")</script>';  
      }  
 } 
 
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert"  />  
                </form>  
                <table >  
                <?php  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_images ";  
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {  
                    echo '  
                        <tr>  
                            <td> <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['name'] ).'" height="200" width="200" /> </td>  
                        </tr>  
                    ';  
                }  
                ?>  
                </table> 
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Edit: the insert doesn't work correctly. it insert the string LOAD_FILE(C:xampphtdocs   est_img4.jpg) instead of the image itself.

Comment: So what part doens't work, the insert or the read?

Comment: @Scuzzy the read doesn't work.

Comment: Have you verified the image is actually stored in the database? It looks like you're inserting the string `LOAD_FILE(C:\xampp\htdocs\test_img\4.jpg)` into the database

Comment: MyISAM is a very old storage engine that doesn't support any of the modern features expected a database like transactions or a journal for data integrity. If you can avoid, and you almost always can, that's something you should do.

Comment: @Joni right I check it now and I realize that I inserting the string LOAD_FILE(C:\xampp\htdocs\test_img\4.jpg) instead of the image itself.I will edit the problem

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BLOB` columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html) can only store 64KB of data, so any images larger than that, which is going to be most, will get truncated and can't be displayed.

You'll want to use `LONGBLOB` if you want to store these in the database.

You also can't insert using `LOAD_FILE` unless the file's present on the same server as the MySQL server process. This is not always the case. If it is present then you should be doing:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_images(name) VALUES (LOAD_FILE(?))");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $path);
$stmt->execute();
```

Where the *path* is quoted, not the `LOAD_FILE` call itself. You're inserting a plain string and the literal text `"LOAD_FILE(...)"` is not valid image data.

Remember, storing images in the database is usually a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay). Store a reference to the image instead, like a file path or URL to an object-store.

You're also serving up images as inline `data:base64` data which is extremely inefficient. Not only does it increase the amount of data required to transmit the image by about 33% but it means the images *must* be sent on each page load and cannot be cached. For mobile users this will burn through data fast.